# PHP Compare strings from different tables

Tags: php

Sorry i really make a mistake on my last "question".. here is the real one..

I have this code.. where i create or generate a coupon code.. when this is used is stored on the users table.. on the users row each user has a Code.. (the coupon they used)...

The table with coupons, and the one with the users and the code coupon they used are different..

This is my code , my Question is...

How can i Compare Strings from different tables.. im really a newbie as you can see.. with really bad english :(

```
<?php

$res = mysql_query("SELECT codigo,used FROM codigos;") 
or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<th>Codigo</th><th>Usado</th><th>Usuario</th>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
echo "<tr>
<td>{$row['codigo']}</td>
<td>";

if(strcmp($row['used'],"0") ==0) {
    echo "No Usado";}
    else {
        echo "Usado"; }
echo "</td>
<td>";

//Here GET THE NAME OF USER WITH THAT CODE

echo "</td>
</tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
}
else
echo 'No rows in selected table';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the basic idea correct. The only missing piece is that the POS (or iPad or whatever the offline store is using) would need to also communicate that coupon up to your server, which would store it in the database, for validation.

As far as security, make sure you one-way hash your data in the database (so it can't be decrypted), and use SSL to transmit any data to and from the server. To validate data against a one-way hash, you need to hash the incoming data and compare the two hashes (since they're basically unique GUIDs, if they match, you know they are exactly the same).